# How do I read font information when reading text from pdf using itext?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have multiple separate pdfs and I want to read the text from them 1 by 1, and write it to a new pdf so they are all in the same document. I dont want to use PdfMerger because that will include all the white space. This is why I want to read and copy the actual text.

The main problem though is the font. The below code is fine for reading and writing all the text, but I lost the font size/type and whether or not its in bold. I need this to format to my destination page. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

```
 byte[] result;                     

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter(ms);                
            PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            //PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(outPdf);
            Document outDocument = new Document(outPdf);

            foreach (var clause in clauses)
            {
                //Add pages from the first document
                var sourceReader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(clause.ClauseBytes));
                var sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(sourceReader);

                for (int i = 0; i < sourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
                {
                    var sourcePage = sourcePdf.GetPage(i+1);
                    var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();                        
                    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(sourcePage, strategy);
                    var currentText = Encoding.
                        UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)));

                    outDocument.Add(new Paragraph(currentText));                                              

                    //merger.Merge(sourcePdf, 1, sourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages());
                    //sourcePdf.Close();
                }
            }
            outDocument.Close();
            //merger.Close();                
            result = ms.GetBuffer();
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Concerning your main problem: You have to create a custom text extraction strategy which extracts style information together with the text. A general solution can be rather tricky to implement... As an aside: Don't use `ms.GetBuffer()`, it returns the PDF plus a tail of garbage bytes. Use `ToArray()` instead.

Comment: I would have thought this would be a common requirement with itext? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: A much more common request concerning text extraction is extracting the *structure* of text, in particular in case of tabular data, and the most powerful iText component for this task, pdf2data, requires a commercial license. The open iText core offers a framework based on which one can implement both tasks (style / structure extraction), but a generic solution is clearly non-trivial in either case.

Comment: So if I get pdf2Data I can extract the text with the font data as well?

Comment: I have not played around with it, so it would be possible but I'm not aware of it. I wanted to express something different, though: iText core contains basic extraction capabilities and a framework for more complex stuff, but for an implementation of more complex stuff based on that framework you either have to do the implementation yourself (using e.g. answers to multiple questions here on stack overflow focusing on detail problems) or ask iTextPdf (or someone else) for a commercial solution.